# Python Background Image Issue - 'Unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So, I just want to upload a background image for a Tkinter program.  I'm using a version of Python above 3 and am fairly new to it.  I'm also using Pillow.  I have this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

canvas = Canvas(width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'blue')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\Documents\PythonStuff\earth7.gif")
canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = image, anchor = NW)

mainloop()
```

And the photo's directory is highlighted showing an error: "'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 188: truncated /uXXXX escape."

Does anyone have any ideas? If so, thanks so much.  First time posting here so I apologize for any formatting issues.

Comment: have you try with different file image or file in different format - ".png" ?

Comment: you can try to use `from PIL import Image` and `img = Image(filename)`, `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)`

Comment: Your filename looks incorrect. You have a single backslash, which is a python escape character. Try using a raw string, or a forward slash (though, I would expect you to get a file not found error, so maybe this isn't your problem).

Comment: Bryan that worked.  Thank you so much!